# Text analysis based on Neural Networks

Tags: android, neural-network, lstm

Consider the situation where we have a message and we want to find word sequences according to a specific pattern. For example:

Pattern - **TIME AND PLACE**

**Message**

> *Hey bro, what's up? :) Now I can't come and help you because I have a lot of work today. Hence, I have no time. But I will be free
>   tomorrow. Can we meet at 3 p.m. near subway?*

**Solution**

> "at 3 p.m. near subway".

This search is done with the help of Neural Networks.

According to the articles I have read, we can realize this idea using:

1. word2vec.
2. Received vectors we pass to the Neural Network and the result is ready.

I assume the type of Neural Networks to use is: LSTM.

All this must be implemented in code for Android.

Can you advice me what I have to use, and how to materialize this idea? Which libraries will be helpful for this?